# passing arrays to a constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have to write two files for an assignment, a client file that will receive two sets of data from the user.  The first set is a list of applicant ID's (int) and the second set is either  y or n (char).  The sets of data need to be entered into two arrays.
I then have to create a class file that will receive these two arrays into a constructor which will then run through some specific methods to validate if the answers are correct, how many answered correctly and finally which candidates received the most correct answers.

I just have two questions:

1st - the first line of data that will be entered into the second array will be the answer key.  Is it possible to add a 0 to the beginning of the applicant ID's array so that the two arrays will match (ID#{1} to answer{1}, etc)?

2nd - with the calling of my class file from my client file do I declare the array's in both?
i.e.:

client file:

```
int[] id = new int[];
char[] answer = new char[];
ValidateMark importClerk = new ValidateMark(id, answer);
```

class constructor:

```
public ValidateMark(int number[], char marks[])
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume the data structures are required and specified as part of the assignment and not give any input on alternate ones to use unless asked otherwise.

First Question:

Yes you can, but not in the manner you are thinking.  Arrays, once declared, occupy a static amount of memory with a static number of elements. Therefore, you can't "insert" a item to the beginning of a array that has already been declared and allocated. That is a dynamic collection type of behavior such as a List.

If you don't have control over the declaration/allocation of the array then the only choice you have is to copy the contents of the array to a new one that includes the empty 0 index.

```
int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
int newArray = new int[array.length + 1];

newArray[0] = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < newArray.length; i++)
{
   newArray[i] = array[i - 1];
}
```

On the other hand, if you are the one making this initial array then just simply make the size +1 bigger and add a zero at the beginning, problem solved.

Second Question:

Whether or not the arrays should declared in the "Client file" (whatever that is), is really up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Your suggestion for creating a new array is what I was looking for.  I just didn't quite know how to make use of it. I am testing my program two way, one where I declare and initialize the array in the program itself and then secondly, where the program will ask the user for the input.  Since the program will never know the actual size of the array when input by user I am setting my constructor to receive the array's as `public ValidateMark(int...number, char...answer)`.  Would this be the correct way for my constructor?

Comment: @NYC Canuck Absolutely. If you will only know after user input then it would be a better design to receive arrays in the constructor. However, if you don't know the number of items the user will give you it is generally preferred to use a dynamic data structure like a linked list. Are you familar with linked lists yet?

Comment: We are still about 6 chapters away from that part of the text.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I will be good to go for a while with this.

Comment: @NYC Canuck np. If you feel this adequately answered your question, don't hesitate to up vote/tick the answer box.

Comment: I was able to tick the answer box, but do not have enough reputation to up vote yet!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you control the definition of the arrays, you can skip elements and start wherever you want.

2) `int[] id = new int[]; char[] answer[] = new char[];` is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So I can start to import the data into my array starting at the [1] postition? and have my [0] default to 0?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "import", I suppose.  (I've no idea why you want to do this, however.)

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  Sorry if my wording is not clear, just starting out with learning how to code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're really looking for is a `Map<Integer,Char>`. This would allow you to explicitly associate the identifier with the answer.

If you already have `int[] id` and `char[] answer` in some part of the code, you can easily convert it to a `Map`:

```
Map<Integer,Char> map = new HashMap<Integer,Char>();
for (int i = 0; i < id.length; id++) {
    map.put(id[i], answer[i]);
}
```

Then, you can make calls like `map.get(id)` to retrieve the answer for that question.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Still a little advanced for the stage of our instruction at this point, but I do appreciate the input.  I can definetly see how thing will get 'easier' yet more complex as I learn more and more about this language.  Thanks again